# METODO BURBUJA ASM ARRAY

Tags: array, ordenamiento, ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel, asm

BUENAS TARDES, QUISIERA PEDIR AYUDA CON EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO DE PROGRAMA. ES UN MÉTODO BURBUJA DE VECTOR EN ENSAMBLADOR .TIENE QUE ORDENAR DE MENOR A MAYOR .APARENTEMENTE TIENE QUE TENER ESTA VISTA DESDE LA CONSOLA. EL PROBLEMA ES AL COMPILAR. ME MARCA ESTE ERROR.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL CODIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE:

```
    .MODEL SMALL

INCLUDE 'EMU8086.INC'



DATA SEGMENT
    
ARRAY DW 00H,00H,00H,00H
    
ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    
    CALL MAIN
  
    MAIN PROC
        CALL VECTOR
        CALL BURBUJA
        MENU
        RET
        MAIN ENDP
    
    MENU MACRO
        PRINTN ""
        PRINTN "SANCHEZ OLVERA JOSE ELIAS SECUENCIA 1CV29"
        PRINTN "::::::::::::::::MENU::::::::::::::::"
        PRINTN "1.-ORDENAR MENOR --> MAYOR"
        PRINTN "2.-SALIR"
        PRINTN ""
        PRINT "OPCION"
        CALL SCAN_NUM
        CAMP CX
        JE CALL IMPRIMIR1
        JMP FIN
        RET 
    ENDM 
    
    VECTOR PROC
        CALL INICIO
        CALL LLENADO
        RET
        VECTOR ENDP 
    
    LLENADO PROC
        PRINT "NUMERO: "
        CALL SCAN_NUM
        MOV [ARRAY + SI], CX
        PRINTN ""
        ADD SI, 02
        INC DX
        CMP DX, 4
        JNE LLENADO
        MOV SI, 0
        MOV DX, 0
        MOV CX, 0
        RET
        LLENADO ENDP
    
    INICIO PROC
        LEA SI,ARRAY
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX
        RET
        INICIO ENDP
    
    FIN PROC
        PRINTN ""
        PRINTN ""
        PRINT "PRESIONE TECLA PARA SALIR"
        MOV AH, 0H
        INT 16H
        MOV AX,4C00H
        INT 21H
        RET 
        FIN ENDP
    
    BURBUJA PROC
        MOV AX, ARRAY[SI]
        MOV BX, ARRAY[SI+2]
        CMP AX, BX
        JA MENOR
        ADD SI, 2
        INC CX
        CMP CX, 4
        JNE BURBUJA
        MOV CX, 0
        MOV SI, 0
        CALL VERIFICARMENOR
        RET
        BURBUJA ENDP
    
    MENOR PROC
    MOV ARRAY[SI], BX
    MOV ARRAY[SI+2], AX
    ADD SI, 2
    INC CX
    JMP CALL BURBUJA
    RET
    MENOR ENDP
    VERIFICARMENOR PROC

    MOV AX, ARRAY[SI]
    MOV BX, ARRAY[SI+2]
    CMP AX,BX
    JA RESETMENOR
    ADD SI, 2
    INC CX
    CMP CX, 4 
    JNE VERIFICARMENOR
    RET  
    VERIFICARMENOR ENDP 

RESETMENOR PROC

    MOV SI, 0
    MOV CX, 0
    JMP CALL BURBUJA
    RET             
    RESETMENOR ENDP

IMPRIMIR1 PROC

    PRINT ""
    PRINT "VECTOR DE MENOR A MAYOR",13,10,'$'
    MOV SI, 0
    MOV SI, 8

    PRINT 

  SCAN_NUM        PROC    NEAR

        PUSH    DX
        PUSH    AX
        PUSH    SI        
        MOV     CX, 0
        ; reset flag:
        MOV     CS:make_minus, 0

make_minus      DB      ?       ; used as a flag.

SCAN_NUM        ENDP

PRINT_NUM       PROC    NEAR

        PUSH    DX
        PUSH    AX
        CMP     AX, 0
 
PRINT_NUM       ENDP    

    
  CODE ENDS
```

Comment: El código tiene aparte del que te muestra otros errores. Hay una línea CAMP CX, supongo que es una comparación. Debería ser CMP  CX. Pero aparte de eso te falta con que lo compara. Te sugiero que vuelvas la original y hagas los cambios con mayor cuidado porque van a salirte otros errores. La siguiente línea ya es un error JE es salta por igual a la etiqueta siguiente pero le estás poniendo un CAll.